# What is required to add opcodes to an existing binary?

Tags: c++, assembly, portable-executable

i am trying to add a single NOP instruction at the very beginning of the .text section in a simple hello world executable that i have written, i know that it is not just that straight forward, so i am using a dissasembling library in order to patch all addresses accordinly(for example if i insert 1 byte opcode into the binary, all addresses after that instruction will be pushed 1 byte forward, so i patch all calls to that address to use the new one).

i am also updating the AddressOfEntryPoint field in the OptionalHeader of the PE header so that the entrypoint is correct, but i am still not getting this to work.

So my question is basicly, what is required of me to "fix" in the executable after adding 1 single nop instruction at the very beginning(and i checked that i do not break any instructions by inserting it). are there more field in the PE header that has to be fixed ? or what am i missing here ? :S

Comment: Why would you want to do this?  Just curious...

Comment: A far easier approach is the ancient virus approach:  Don't try to insert something at the beginning... Overwrite something at the entry point and jump to something that you've *appended*.  Reimplement whatever you've overwritten at the end of your code and then jump back to where things should have been.  Sort of a "detour"

Comment: i am trying to make en engine for adding functionality to existing binaries using assembly, i am not looking to do this any other way either :P and i do know i can't just put in random instructions that woud modify stack/registers ofc..

Comment: yeah i could detour, but i am looking to add mid code instructions in several places, not just to run my code in a detour :) i know this won't be simple but i have enough time on my hands :P

Comment: I honestly believe that you are adding unreasonable conditions and overcomplicating the problem.  Sorry. :)

Comment: Well you can believe that, but this is the way that i want to go about this :)

Answer (score 2):

You very probably have to [relocate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relocation_%28computing%29) your binary executable (which might not be possible in the general case, e.g. for [stripped binaries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stripped_binary)). Dive into Levine's [*Linkers and loaders*](http://www.iecc.com/linker/) book.

If you can recompile that executable, consider adding some [plugin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plug-in_%28computing%29) abilities to it (and use [dynamic linking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_linker)).

Comment: Yeah, i am relocating all addresses and data used in the executable by x amount of bytes that i have pushed the given resource forward in the executable, keep in mind that this is a static executable and not a running process.